In oracle VM VirtualBox at version 7.0.14 unable to see sd card in usb devices
I am trying to remove write protection of sd card by manjaro So I did this on VM but the problem comes when I can't see my sd card in the vm but I can see it in host window.
And I have mounted sd card in laptops inbuilt sd card slot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
